# Is there a NPM package for instagram auth implimentation in react native?(Expo)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, instagram

I have successfully integrated facebook and google authentication in my `react native` application.

I have not ejected the application its still running on `Expo`.

For Facebook i found `expo-facebook` NPM package and for google i found `expo-google-app-auth` NPM package and with the help of some blogs i successfully integrated the functionality.

But in case of Instagram i cant find any proper documentation or blogs for the auth implementation.

**Do Instagram have an `auth` implementation for `react native` and if there is can it implemented in `Expo` and how** ??

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-login)?

Comment: @J.Doe Its a third party library right ? . I really wanted to confirm is there something official like there is for Facebook or Google in Expo for Instagram.